# Google Identity Services - oauth2 initCodeClient method is not skipping account selection using select_account

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, selection, account, skip

I am using this auth-code flow with the use of [initCodeClient](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/reference/js-reference#google.accounts.oauth2.initCodeClient) .

It says in the options that 'select_account' is set to `false` by default.

[select_account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOjNQ.png)

However, after logging out, then logging in, I am still presented with the account selection screen from the dialog.

Is it possible to skip the account selection on the next logins?

I tried using the 'hint' and 'select_account' options, adding them explicitly.